# Facebook comment box and like box are not loading most of the time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-likebox

I have placed the following code the first thing in the head section of the page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=324524777119";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and the facebook comment box in the where I want to appear on the page:

```
<div id="fbcomments"></div>
<script>
var elemDiv = document.getElementById("fbcomments");
var markup = '';
markup += '<fb:comments href="' + location.href + '" data-num-posts="10" data-width="728"></fb:comments>';
elemDiv.innerHTML = markup;
FB.XFBML.parse(elemDiv);
</script>
```

and the same for the like box:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Gags-All-Day/185515594882366" data-width="336" data-height="500" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

The problem is that sometimes the comment box and like box does not show up on the page. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The JS-SDK should be placed in the body section, preferably after the opening `<body>` tag.
Also if there's no real reason to use a script for your comment plugin then just include it directly to your markup.